# How to modify an angular variable string that is passed to a php

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to access the forms variables in my angularjs function per below (example s1 = Joe Smith).

But I need to modify the Indata variable to replace the  a_searchvalue1 with what is in s1 with quote around it.

Orginal:

```
    var Indata = { what_to_do: "angular_users5",  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"a_earchvalue1","sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]' }
```

so that is reads (note a_searchvalue1 is replaced with Joe Smith)

```
    var Indata = { what_to_do: "angular_users5",  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"Joe Smith","sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]' }





<div id="myapp"  ng-controller="empcontroller">
    <input id="name1"  type="text" placeholder="Name"    required name="Name" value="Joe Smith">
    <input id="email1" type="text" placeholder="Email"   required name="Email" value="webcastpoa@gmail.com">
    <p id="sample">demo1</p>
    <button ng-click="postData()">Submit</button><br>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    app.controller('empcontroller', function($scope, $http)
                   {

                   $scope.postData = function ()
                   {
                   var s1 =  document.getElementById("name1").value;
                   alert(s1);

                   var Indata = { what_to_do: "angular_users5",  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"a_earchvalue1","sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]' }

                   var req =
                   {
                   method: 'POST',url: 'angular_master.php',
                   headers: {'Content-Type':undefined},
                   params: Indata
                   }

                   $http(req).then(function (response)
                                   {
                                   $scope.names = response.data.records;
                                   document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED THE BUTTON";

                                   alert(angular.toJson(response.data.records));


                                   });

                   }

                   });


    </script>
```

also how can I handle if user put double quotes in input field

Comment: Use `ng-model` to bind object to input. You rarely ever use dom methods like `getElementById` in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `where_clause` key is a taking JSON array as a string you can use string concatenation like this:-

```
var Indata = {
  what_to_do: "angular_users5",
  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"'+s1+'",          
  "sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]'
}
```

This will replace the value of a_searchvalue1 with s1 with quotes around it.
See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- var Indata = { what_to_do: "angular_users5",  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":s1,"sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]' }
- use encodeURIComponent()